# iOS8 query notification style setting

Tags: ios, ios8, push-notification

I up voted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608782/is-it-possible-for-an-app-to-query-what-notification-style-is-set-for-the-app) duplicate but it's over 2 years old so I don't think it gets seen.  So asking again, sorry if that's bad practice.

In my iOS8 app I want to display notifications that occur while the app is running in a similar style to how they are displayed when the app isn't running.  In order to do this, I need to know what the system setting is.  I have seen these:

`currentUserNotificationSettings` - lets me get the states of the sounds/badge/alert options... just the on/off options.  Not the actual style: None, Banner, Alert.

`isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` - again, just lets me check if enabled, but not the STYLE.

Just trying to give a consistent experience for notifications, not based on if my app happens to be in the foreground or not.  Too much to ask? :)

p.s.-Don't think it matters, but my app uses both local and remote notifications.

Comment: There was a property back then which is deprecated in iOS 8.
It is the UIApplication enabledRemoteNotificationTypes.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/enabledRemoteNotificationTypes

EDIT: I don't think they made a new alternative for this after deprecating it.

Comment: I'd be more than happy using a depreciated property, as long as it works for this release... but pretty sure that property doesn't give me what I'm after.  I think UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert will be set if they have banner style or alert style set, so doesn't tell me which of the two styles they are using.

Comment: Here are its possible values:
   UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone    = 0,
   UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge   = 1 << 0,
   UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound   = 1 << 1,
   UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert   = 1 << 2,
   UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability = 1 << 3